# How to remove Python3.8 and Install Python3.6 as default Python in Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: xubuntu, uninstall, python3, cuda

completely new here, I was working around from last 2 days to remove the python3.8 from ubuntu 20.04 and install python3.6 as default python. But the issue is when I tried to uninstall or purge python3.8 it removes everything such as all the packages and display drivers and CUDA etc.

How to do that, Is there any way ?

Comment: I don't know why many or some try to this, please read up on the role python3 plays in the overall operations of the Ubuntu OS. Please don't do that unless your one of the Ubuntu developers! Look for a version of CUDA that can live with your version of python3 or update the CUDA configurations to use that python version... Please don't change the official OS python3 version...

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1534210/use-different-python-version-with-virtualenv your answer is virtualenv, do not modify system wide python installation as it's needed by many system packages.

Comment: @DanieleGamba Thanks, I think your suggestion is good. I will try it.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest not to remove the installed Python 3.8, as maybe it is used for system tools.

I'd suggest to add the [deadsnake-ppa](https://launchpad.net/~deadsnakes/+archive/ubuntu/ppa) then you can install all common Python versions in parallel.